# How to set Horizontal ListView item to most right

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-view

I have implemented a custom Listview which is HorizontalListView.

Here is the [HorizontalListView](https://pastebin.com/CjCrcUmQ) class. One of the other classes required is: [Utils](https://pastebin.com/JHYhtT7M).

With the help of the above two classes, I have implemented HorizontalListView below:

```
  <com.example.myproject.HorizontalListView
                android:id="@+id/imageList"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:stackFromBottom="true"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
```

But the issue is, I am not getting the Listview on the right side. What I want is to start the listview from the right side. But I don't know where to update the code.

I have tried to set gravity to Right side for XML layout and for Java class but I'm not getting the correct effect.

I am not getting listview to start from the right side.

I want just like below screen shot:

[image: Screen Shot]

My other XML code is as below:

```
     <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/Idea_titleET"
                        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/signup_edittext_backgroung"
                        android:cursorVisible="true"
                        android:ellipsize="start"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                        android:hint="Title"
                        android:inputType="textCapWords"
                        android:maxLength="45"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Idea_TitleEr"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="6dp"
                    android:text="Title is required"
                    android:textColor="#ff0000"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/Idea_DescriptionET"
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/signup_edittext_backgroung"
                    android:gravity="top|right"
                    android:hint="Description"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="3"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Upload Documents"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="The document can be images(JPG, PNG) or Youtube videos(URL)"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >



                    <com.example.lc5plus.HorizontalListView
                        android:id="@+id/imageList"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="130dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="right" />
                </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Check below image for what I want:

[image]

In above image, square with "+" sign is my Horizontal listView. Right now there is only one index is added, but it is showing at left side. So what I want is, even if there is only one index, it should display at right side.

Comment: Post the rest of your xml.

Comment: @MikeOrtiz please check my question. i have added xml code.

Answer (score 0):

convert this

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="vertical" >



                <com.example.lc5plus.HorizontalListView
                    android:id="@+id/imageList"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="130dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

to

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:orientation="vertical" >



                <com.example.lc5plus.HorizontalListView
                    android:id="@+id/imageList"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="130dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Just try it , it may or may not work. Just a try.

Comment: Its not helping. Please help me with another option. also check question. I have added XML code.

Comment: i couldnt answer more because your question is not clear to me. I dont understand what you want. Try to be as specific as possible. Try to add more images. Take some time to write your question more clearly.

Comment: i have updated my question again. Please check it. Hope you got my point now.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:stackFromBottom="false"
```

make it false,and try again?

Comment: Its not helping. Please help me with another option. also check question. I have added XML code.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a little change in your xml add two lines `android:stackFromBottom="true"` and `android:transcriptMode="normal"` and set width to `match_parent` like below:

```
<com.example.myproject.HorizontalListView
                android:id="@+id/imageList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:stackFromBottom="true"
                android:transcriptMode="normal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
```

As **yahya** said, I noticed your custom horizontal **listview** is not overriding the **stackFromBottom** feature as a **listview** overriding this feature, please first override that functionality and then apply above code. For reference you can check [**this link**](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java)

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Its not helping. Please help me with another option. also check question. I have added XML code.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to see horizontal listview code of yours, but are you sure that your horizontal listview supports stackFromBottom attribute? Otherwise you will need to implement that by yourself.

Comment: I have try that but not getting any effect on that.

Answer (score 0):

if your mean is rtl ,Just use this :

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

that's all :)